# Probability of event A given B and C

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The best example of this problem I could come up with is a hypothetical MMA match.

Assume the probability that fighter 1 wins by submission (Event B) is $50$% or $0.5$ and the probability that fighter 2 loses by submission (Event C) is $70$% or $0.7$. What would be the probability that fighter 1 beats fighter 2 by submission (Event A)?

Would that be $P(A|(B∩C))$? Also is that the same as $P(A|B) ∩ P(A|C)$?
In this case the $P(B∩C) = P(B) * P(C) = 0.7 * 0.5 = 0.35$ which does not make sense. What am I missing?

Or is it as simple as $P(C) + P(B) - P(A∩B) = 0.7 + 0.5 - 0.35 = 0.85$? As in fighter 1 wins by submission or fighter 2 loses by submission?

Comment: Although I don't know what "winning by submission" means, the scenario you described is impossible since whoever wins is not a random event that depends on the previous winning probabilities of each player. Either: $P(1 \text{ wins})=1- P(2 \text{ loses})$ which is not your case since $0.5+0.7\neq 1$, or if your talking about career stats, that has no influence on the outcome of a fight, they're statistics, not probabilities.

Comment: Also, that conditional formula is doesn't have mathematical meaning since probabilities are numbers and therefore cannot be intersected as sets.

Comment: @Bcpicao I see. Thanks for the answer. In short it is impossible to predict the outcome given their previous statistics? In this case, anyways.

Comment: Yes, to give you an example, think that two Floyd Maywheathers were going to battle on the ring. They both have 100% win rates, does that mean there won't be a winner?

Comment: Actually, people use ELO ratings in chess (supposedly a game of pure skill) to estimate probabilities of winning, so I don't see why that can't apply here. You simply don't have nearly enough information in what you have provided. Maybe the best way is to match up $100$ fighters with $0.5$ win-by-submission rates with $100$ fighters with $0.7$ lose-by-submission rates and see what happens. Even then there might be other stats that you should have paid attention to.

Comment: By the way, when Fighter 1 meets Fighter 2 in this scenario, $B$ and $C$ are the **same** event, not opposite, which just goes to show how imprecisely this question is defined.

Comment: @DavidK the probabilities of winning in a chess game are calculated based on your current ELO as a relatively meaningful gage for your strength and not on your W/L record, the paradigm is completely different. You could actually apply ELO to boxing (as long as you consider it as a zero-sum game), could be fun :)

Comment: @DavidK you are correct. Let me change the question title.

Comment: @Bcpicao I agree. The point about ELO was just that past statistics **can** inform present probabilities. But in this case the past statistics are nothing like ELO ratings and there's no obvious way to estimate any probability from them. As I said, "not enough information."

Comment: Would it be correct to say that I'd be better off to perform some sort of a regression analysis with the given statistics and then try to get a prediction based on the results?

Answer (score -1):

There is not nearly enough information.

Here are two scenarios showing the figure could range from $0\%$ to $100\%$, and many other scenarios and any intermediate figure is also possible

```
                                  Scenario 1    Scenario 2 
 
Prob 1 beats 2 by submission            0%          100%
Prob 1 beats 3 by submission           70%           40%
Prob 1 beats 4 by submission           70%           40%
Prob 1 beats 5 by submission           60%           20%
 
Prob 2 loses to 1 by submission         0%          100%
Prob 2 loses to 3 by submission        90%           50% 
Prob 2 loses to 4 by submission        90%           50%
Prob 2 loses to 5 by submission       100%           80%
```

Comment: I'm confused. In the second row Prob of A beating B by submission is 70% and the opposite is 40% and yet their sum is more than 100%?

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the questions of the OP.

Comment: @Nick202 - I have replaced A,B,C,D with 1,2,3,4.  So now it is clearer "Prob 1 beats 2 by submission" and "Prob 2 loses to 1 by submission" are equal in each scenario

Comment: @Bcpicao - I am trying to show that there is no answer just using the information provided.